# Spark DataFrame Parallelism

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my usecase i am using Apache Spark

1) I have around 2500 Parquet files on HDFS, file size varies from file to file.

2) I need to process each parquet files and build a new DataFrame and write a new DataFrame into orc file format.

3) My Spark driver program is like this.
I am iterating  each file, processing single parquet file creating a new DataFrame and writing a new DataFrame as ORC, below is the code snippet.

```
  val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
  val parquetDFMap = fs.listStatus(new Path(inputFilePath)).map(folder => {
  (folder.getPath.toString, sqlContext.read.parquet(folder.getPath.toString))})

parquetDFMap.foreach {
  dfMap =>
    val parquetFileName = dfMap._1
    val parqFileDataFrame = dfMap._2
    for (column <- parqFileDataFrame.columns) 
    {
       val rows = parqFileDataFrame.select(column)
            .mapPartitions(lines => lines.filter(filterRowsWithNullValues(_))
            .map(row => buildRowRecords(row, masterStructArr.toArray, valuesArr)))
        val newDataFrame: DataFrame = parqFileDataFrame.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, StructType(masterStructArr))
       newDataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").save(orcOutPutFilePath+tableName)
    }
}
```

The problem with this design I am able to process only one parquet file in time, parallelism is applied only when I create a new data frame and when the new DataFrame is written into ORC format. So if any of the tasks like creating a new DataFrame or writing a new DataFrame in to ORC take long time to complete other lined up parquet processing is stuck until the current parquet operation gets completed.

Can you please help me with a better approach or design for this usecase.

Comment: did you solve this issue? If so how it worked?

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram I have used `parquetDFMap.par.foreach {`, If you have any better approach let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a single data frame for all the parquet files instead of one dataframe for each file

```
val df =  sqlContext.read.parquet(inputFilePath)
df.map(row => convertToORc(row))
```

Comment: Raju I can't create a single Data Frame for all parquet files, as I need to work on each column of each parquet files come up with the new DataFrame. Even if I go with your approach still I will not benefit from parallelism as I need to loop every parquet file to create on huge DataFrame.

Comment: Guys how about doing this "parquetDFMap.par.foreach {"

Comment: I am able to achieve parallelism by adding parquetDFMap.par.foreach {, but can some one help me on how spark driver figure out number of threads for parallelizing forloop

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parallelise the parquet file processing by paralleling the by doing `parquetDFMap.foreach.par`